# Deserializing Google transliteration in C# using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, transliteration

As a beginner I tried to deserialize Google transliterator return array. It's a JSON array like this:

```
[{"ew" : "namaste","hws" : ["नमस्ते","नमसते","नमास्ते",]},]
```

pretty awesome!

This is my c# class used for deserialization:

```
   [Serializable]
   public class googleTransliterator  
   {

       [JsonProperty("ew")]
       public String sourceWord { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("hws")]
       public String[] transliteratedWords { get; set; }

   }
```

and finally:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
...
// return value from google transliteration API is in streamReader
var s = new JsonSerializer();
var gt = (googleTransliterator) s.Deserialize( new StringReader( streamReader.ReadToEnd()), typeof( googleTransliterator));
```

And what I got is:

```
Cannot create and populate list type GoogleTransliterator.googleTransliterator.
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is an array of JSON objects (`[{...},]`) instead of a plain object (`{...}`).

Your code should work if you change it like this:

```
var gt = ((googleTransliterator[])s.Deserialize(
    new StringReader(streamReader.ReadToEnd()),
    typeof(googleTransliterator[])))[0];
```

Comment: sorry, not workin. error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I've edited my code. Could you try it again? (And probably debug and tell _which_ object is null, if the problem persists?)

Comment: sorry, your first answer was OK, it was my mistake. google transliteration API has an option for alternate response and I did not use the correct option. thanks man. U rock.

Comment: And I was just guessing hehe ;)